# Gödel's ontological proof & Benzmüller's work

Tags: mathematical-philosophy, proof-assistants

For a decade or so, Christoph Benzmüller from Berlin has explored Gödel's ontological proof (and variants) of existence of God. He uses the proof assistant Isabelle/HOL. He recently posted a [preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342159229_A_Simplified_Supreme_Being_Necessarily_Exists_says_the_Computer_Computationally_Explored_Variants_of_Godel%27s_Ontological_Argument), which was highlighted by the cover of the French magazine [Science et Vie](https://www.science-et-vie.com/archives/pourquoi-on-croit-en-dieu-les-mathematiques-ont-enfin-la-reponse-57595).

Well, I am not familiar with AI, yet even less with applications to metaphysics. But many practitioners of MO must be. I should like to know how serious is Benzmüller's work considered in this community. Is it controversial or is this considered a respectable research activity ?

Comment: My recollection is that Goedel's proof is fine, given his axioms, and that there is a single axiom that almost all philosophers do not find convincing.

Comment: You say "I recently posted a [preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342159229_A_Simplified_Supreme_Being_Necessarily_Exists_says_the_Computer_Computationally_Explored_Variants_of_Godel%27s_Ontological_Argument)", but the link is to a paper "A (Simplified) Supreme Being Necessarily Exists, says the Computer: Computationally Explored Variants of Gödel's Ontological Argument" by Benzmüller (not, I guess, you).  Is that intentional?

Comment: The Ontological argument, in its modern modal versions, hinges on the premise of whether God is possible or not, the rest being in my view mostly distractions including discussions of S5 and what not. As a fairly old-fashioned Thomist, I think Aquinas' criticism is decisive which can be construed as saying that the proof works but only God knows it.

Comment: @G.Rodrigues: Dipping our toes into philosophy, one can say that according to Descartes, if God thinks about the proof, then he exists; but following a more Douglas Adams route, if God knows that he exists, then he doesn't have to think about it, and therefore disappears from existence!

Comment: @LSpice. Oups! Of course, I meant *He recently posted*.

Comment: The title of Science and Vie is "Existence de Dieu : les mathématiques ont enfin la réponse", that is clearly a big deformation of the (mathematical) onthological argument. My personal point of view, with all due respect for Goedel, is that "Mathematics" and "existence of God" should not stay in the same sentence.

Comment: If you look at the article, he says one could rephrase the statement to be about the following property: "An entity $x$ is maximally-rational ($\mathcal{G}$) iff it has all rational/consistent properties." What looks particularly mathematically interesting is that an automated theorem prover was used to explore ways to trim down the assumptions and the needed logical strength to go from them to the conclusion. In this way Benzmüller also reduced unintended side effects of the conclusion that followed from the stronger logical axioms.

Comment: A very naive question. Why do we need modal logic to formalize the ontological argument? Already Gödel uses modal logic, but why is the argument nor formalizable usual logic?

Comment: @Joël : One of the traditional formulations of the ontological argument relies heavily on the word "necessary." So it is natural, when formalizing the argument, to use a logic where the word "necessary" has a direct formalization.

Comment: I'd be personally interested in a proof of the equivalence between the existence of God and the truth of RH :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila God is calculating the question for the answer 42. He or She's busy. Therefore He or She (or It ?) exists.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: God would not be busy calculating the answer to the wrong question. People always forget that part.

Answer (score 10):

Gödel’s proof has the nice feature that one can cleanly separate the logical core of the argument (which is uncontroversial—but see the next paragraph) from its alleged application to theology (which of course is going to be controversial).  My opinion is that the main significance of Gödel’s proof is that it shows that there is *something* to the ontological argument; many people (including my teenage self), when first encountering the ontological argument, perceive it to be total nonsense.  Immanuel Kant’s “existence is not a predicate” objection was taken by many to be a decisive refutation.  So showing that the ontological argument isn’t completely free of content is already a significant intellectual achievement.

The work of Benzmüller (and Paleo) is interesting because it showed that a (fixable) mistake in Gödel’s proof was more serious than people had previously realized.  See [The Inconsistency in Gödel’s Ontological Argument: A Success Story for AI in Metaphysics](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/16/Papers/137.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Aside from Kant's objection on ontological arguments, I think the strongest criticism to Gödel's ontological proof is that his axioms imply modal collapse, that is, $\varphi \rightarrow \square \varphi$, which somehow undermines the point of modal logic. (That Gödel's axioms imply modal collapse was also verified in another work of Benzmüller and Paleo.)

Answer (score 4):

I know Benzmüller's work from a slightly different context, formalizing other interesting systems of modal logic. Hadn't heard of this specific project, but it seems very admirable.

- Formalization of proofs is a highly respectable activity
- Any "proof of existence of God" written by Gödel is bound to inspire curiosity and interest in logic among the public, thus contributing to education